# Columns in Dynamic Pivot don't start over at next key item

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

This is a continuation from other questions that have been partially answered, but I think the current state is lost now.

To start, I have a temp table where I have stored some variables that are used to query a database.  From there I have built a temp table to identify the visits that meet certain criteria in the following query:

```
SELECT
    spl.trac_id
    ,CONVERT(DATE,pev.CONTACT_DATE) AS 'Contact'

INTO
    #medmtemp

FROM 
    #SAMHSA_PAT_LIST spl
    INNER JOIN dbo.IDENTITY_ID_VIEW iiv
    ON iiv.IDENTITY_ID=spl.MRN
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PAT_ENC_VIEW pev
    ON pev.PAT_ID = iiv.PAT_ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PAT_ENC_RSN_VISIT_VIEW rsn
    ON rsn.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID=pev.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

WHERE
    pev.CONTACT_DATE >= @Start_Date
    AND pev.CONTACT_DATE < @End_Date
    AND pev.APPT_STATUS_C IN ( 2 , 6 , 8 , 9 )
    AND rsn.ENC_REASON_ID = 590;
```

From there I've created a pivot query as follows:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
        ,@PVT_COL NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @PVT_COL =@PVT_COL + '[mm_'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(4))+'],'
    FROM #medmtemp
SELECT @PVT_COL = LEFT(@PVT_COL,LEN(@PVT_COL)-1)

SELECT @SQL = 
N'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [trac_id], Contact ,''mm_''+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS COL_NME 
FROM #medmtemp
)AS A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Contact) FOR COL_NME IN (' + @PVT_COL + ')
)PVT'

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Unfortunately the results I'm seeing are this:

```
trac_id mm_1    mm_2    mm_3    mm_4    mm_5    mm_6    mm_7    mm_8    mm_9    mm_10   mm_11   mm_12   mm_13   mm_14   mm_15   mm_16   mm_17   mm_18   mm_19   mm_20
001 2017-03-01  2017-03-08  2017-03-13  2017-03-16  2017-03-16  2017-03-17  2017-03-22  2017-03-23  2017-03-23  2017-03-24  2017-03-27  2017-03-27  2017-03-30  2017-03-31  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
005 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-02-16  2017-03-18  2017-03-08  NULL    NULL    NULL
008 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-03-08  2017-03-23  2017-03-30
```

Where I want the data to be formatted as:

```
trac_id mm_1    mm_2    mm_3    mm_4    mm_5    mm_6    mm_7    mm_8    mm_9    mm_10   mm_11   mm_12   mm_13   mm_14
1   3/1/2017    3/8/2017    3/13/2017   3/16/2017   3/16/2017   3/17/2017   3/22/2017   3/23/2017   3/23/2017   3/24/2017   3/27/2017   3/27/2017   3/30/2017   3/31/2017
5   2/16/2017   3/18/2017   3/8/2017    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   3/8/2017    3/23/2017   3/30/2017   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Even better would be if the NULL columns were blank, but that's more a nice to have.  I'm hoping I can get this solved as I'll be using this same format of PIVOT in multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

The key is including `partition by trac_id` in the `row_number()`

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ',' + quotename('mm_'
          + right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
          )
      from t 
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'');

select @sql = '
 select trac_id, ' + @cols + '
  from  (
    select 
        trac_id
      , contact = convert(char(10),contact,120)
      , rn=''mm_''+right(''0'' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
      from t
      ) as a
 pivot (max([contact]) for [rn] in (' + @cols + ') ) p';
 select @sql as CodeGenerated;
 exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XDVOTD39040

returns:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                        CodeGenerated                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  select trac_id, [mm_01],[mm_02],[mm_03],[mm_04],[mm_05],[mm_06],[mm_07],[mm_08],[mm_09],[mm_10],[mm_11],[mm_12],[mm_13],[mm_14]                             |
|       from  (                                                                                                                                                |
|         select                                                                                                                                               |
|             trac_id                                                                                                                                          |
|           , contact = convert(char(10),contact,120)                                                                                                          |
|           , rn='mm_'+right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (                                                                                     |
|                   partition by trac_id                                                                                                                       |
|                   order by     contact                                                                                                                       |
|               )),2)                                                                                                                                          |
|           from t                                                                                                                                             |
|           ) as a                                                                                                                                             |
|      pivot (max([contact]) for [rn] in ([mm_01],[mm_02],[mm_03],[mm_04],[mm_05],[mm_06],[mm_07],[mm_08],[mm_09],[mm_10],[mm_11],[mm_12],[mm_13],[mm_14]) ) p |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| trac_id |   mm_01    |   mm_02    |   mm_03    |   mm_04    |   mm_05    |   mm_06    |   mm_07    |   mm_08    |   mm_09    |   mm_10    |   mm_11    |   mm_12    |   mm_13    |   mm_14    |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     001 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-13 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-17 | 2017-03-22 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-24 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-31 |
|     005 | 2017-02-16 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-18 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     011 | 2017-02-16 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-30 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     013 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-13 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-17 | 2017-03-22 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-24 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-31 | NULL       |
|     040 | 2017-02-20 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     043 | 2017-02-03 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     059 | 2017-03-08 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     060 | 2017-02-08 | 2017-03-07 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     067 | 2017-01-24 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|     068 | 2017-02-13 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

---

To convert `null` values to empty strings:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @select_cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ',' + quotename('mm_'
          + right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
          )
      from t 
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'');

select @select_cols = (
    select distinct 
      char(10)+'        , ' + quotename('mm_'
          + right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
          ) +' = isnull('+
        quotename('mm_'
          + right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
          )+','''')'
      from t 
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')

select @sql = '
 select trac_id' + @select_cols + '
 from  (
    select 
        trac_id
      , contact = convert(char(10),contact,120)
      , rn=''mm_''+right(''0'' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by trac_id 
              order by     contact
          )),2)
    from t
      ) as a
 pivot (max([contact]) for [rn] in (' + @cols + ') ) p';
 select @sql as CodeGenerated;
 exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HDTK5946

returns:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                        CodeGenerated                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     select trac_id                                                                                                                                           |
|         , [mm_01] = isnull([mm_01],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_02] = isnull([mm_02],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_03] = isnull([mm_03],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_04] = isnull([mm_04],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_05] = isnull([mm_05],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_06] = isnull([mm_06],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_07] = isnull([mm_07],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_08] = isnull([mm_08],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_09] = isnull([mm_09],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_10] = isnull([mm_10],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_11] = isnull([mm_11],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_12] = isnull([mm_12],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_13] = isnull([mm_13],'')                                                                                                                       |
|         , [mm_14] = isnull([mm_14],'')                                                                                                                       |
|      from  (                                                                                                                                                 |
|         select                                                                                                                                               |
|             trac_id                                                                                                                                          |
|           , contact = convert(char(10),contact,120)                                                                                                          |
|           , rn='mm_'+right('0' +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (                                                                                     |
|                   partition by trac_id                                                                                                                       |
|                   order by     contact                                                                                                                       |
|               )),2)                                                                                                                                          |
|         from t                                                                                                                                               |
|           ) as a                                                                                                                                             |
|      pivot (max([contact]) for [rn] in ([mm_01],[mm_02],[mm_03],[mm_04],[mm_05],[mm_06],[mm_07],[mm_08],[mm_09],[mm_10],[mm_11],[mm_12],[mm_13],[mm_14]) ) p |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| trac_id |   mm_01    |   mm_02    |   mm_03    |   mm_04    |   mm_05    |   mm_06    |   mm_07    |   mm_08    |   mm_09    |   mm_10    |   mm_11    |   mm_12    |   mm_13    |   mm_14    |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     001 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-13 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-17 | 2017-03-22 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-24 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-31 |
|     005 | 2017-02-16 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-18 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     011 | 2017-02-16 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-30 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     013 | 2017-03-08 | 2017-03-13 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16 | 2017-03-17 | 2017-03-22 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-24 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-27 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-30 | 2017-03-31 |            |
|     040 | 2017-02-20 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     043 | 2017-02-03 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     059 | 2017-03-08 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     060 | 2017-02-08 | 2017-03-07 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     067 | 2017-01-24 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|     068 | 2017-02-13 |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Many thanks @SqlZim.  So, replacing what you've listed as 't' with the name of the source temp table gives me what I'm after.  The last question is, can I then insert this into a new temp table?

Comment: @Erik Sure. You can use a global temp table from inside the dynamic code   `select ... into ##pivoted` e.g. http://rextester.com/EQDH71409

Comment: If I just add select * into ##pivoted I get the following error: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: @Erik did you look at the demo?

Comment: I just took another look @SqlZim.  I misread it the first time and put it in the wrong location.  That works now.  One quick question, if I insert the pivot results in a temp table, but need to do another pivot later on I won't have to declare again, but can reuse from below that correct?

Comment: @Erik I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If you need to create another pivot, you will need to drop the existing global temp table first or use a different name. If you just mean you need to select rows from the created global temp table multiple times as you process some other records for stuff, then you are correct.

Comment: I think I'll set a new question as you definitely answered this one. Thank you for the help.